# Java comparable not working in List

Tags: java, comparable

```
public class Variable implements Comparable<Variable> {
String name;
String type;

public Variable(String name, String type){
    this.name = name;
    this.type = type;
}

public String getName(){
    return name;
}

public String getType(){
    return type;
}

public boolean equals(Object o){
    if(o != null && (o instanceof Variable)) {
        return ((Variable)o).getName().equals(name) &&
               ((Variable)o).getType().equals(type);
    }
    return false;
}

public int compareTo(Variable v){
    if (type.compareTo(v.type) != 0) return type.compareTo(v.type);
    return name.compareTo(v.name);
}

public String toString(){
    return type+" "+name;
}
```

}

```
public class Operation implements Comparable<Operation>{
String name;
String type;
List<Variable> arguments;   

public Operation(String name, String type){
    this.name = name;
    this.type = type;
    arguments = new ArrayList<Variable>();
}

public void addArgument(Variable a){
    arguments.add(a);
}   

public String getName(){
    return name;
}

public String getType(){
    return type;
}

public List<Variable> getArguments(){
    return arguments;
}

public int getArgumentNumber(){
    return arguments.size();
}

public boolean equals(Object o){
    if(o != null && (o instanceof Operation)) {
        List<Variable> oa = ((Operation)o).getArguments();
        Collection.sort(arguments);
        Collection.sort(oa);
        return ((Operation)o).getName().equals(name) &&
               ((Operation)o).getType().equals(type) &&
               ((Operation)o).getArguments().equals(arguments);
    }
    return false;
}

public int compareTo(Operation v){
    if (type.compareTo(v.type) != 0) return type.compareTo(v.type);
    else if(name.compareTo(v.name) != 0) return name.compareTo(v.name);
    else{
        if (arguments.size() < v.getArgumentNumber()) return -1;
        else if(arguments.size() > v.getArgumentNumber()) return 1;
        else 
    }
}

public String toString(){
    String s = "";
    if (arguments.isEmpty()) return type + " " + name + "(" +  ")";
    else {
        for(Variable v:arguments){
            s+= v.type + " ";
        }
    }
    return type + " " + name + "(" + s.trim() + ")";
}
```

}

As you can see, in the equals function of Operation class

```
public boolean equals(Object o){
    if(o != null && (o instanceof Operation)) {
        List<Variable> oa = ((Operation)o).getArguments();
        Collection.sort(arguments);
        Collection.sort(oa);
        return ((Operation)o).getName().equals(name) &&
               ((Operation)o).getType().equals(type) &&
               ((Operation)o).getArguments().equals(arguments);
    }
    return false;
}
```

I try to sort the list of Variable, but it give me error message "The method sort(List) is undefined for the type Collection", but I have already defined compareTo function in Variable class.

PS. anyone have idea that how should i define compareTo function in Operation class, should i sort first arguments and then compareTo each Variable?

Thanks.

Comment: You may want to use a good IDE with code completion. This kind of thing is basic debugging. Note that many of the static methods that have been added to Java are in classes that cannot be instantiated. These usually end with an `s` character as they contain methods for *all* related classes and instances. So for `Collection` you've got `Collections` that also contains methods for `List`, `Set` etc. Similarly there's `Files`, and enumerations like `StandardCharsets`.

Comment: It's supposed to be `Collections.sort`, not `Collection.sort`. Also, never override `equals()` without overriding `hashCode()`.

Comment: Thanks alot, I use Eclipse to coding, and it have an import for Collection which made me confuse.

Comment: @RealSkeptic what will happen if I didnt override hashCode() ?

Comment: @MaartenBodewes that's what I'm trying to complete.

Comment: Two equal instances of your class would have two different hashCodes. This violates the `hashCode` contract.

Comment: is there any pattern to create hasCode, or I just pick a random number.@RealSkeptic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the wrong class to sort. `Collection.sort` does not exist, while [`Collections.sort`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort-java.util.List-) does.

```
public boolean equals(Object o){
    if(o != null && (o instanceof Operation)) {
        List<Variable> oa = ((Operation)o).getArguments();
        Collections.sort(arguments);
        Collections.sort(oa);
        return ((Operation)o).getName().equals(name) &&
               ((Operation)o).getType().equals(type) &&
               ((Operation)o).getArguments().equals(arguments);
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: After that Collections.sort(arguments), is this variable modified permanently or only in this function?

Comment: Collections.sort always works in-place. If you want to avoid this, copy the list first, and then sort that copy.

Answer (score 0):

Collection**s**, as in plural, with an 's'.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#method.summary

Answer (score 0):

> PS. anyone have idea that how should i define compareTo function in
>   Operation class, should i sort first arguments and then compareTo each
>   Variable?

Since you rely on the order of `arguments` in your `Operation` class consider to store the `Variable`s in `arguments` in a sorted order already.
This means eiter sort the `List` with every new added `Variable` or use a `Set` instead of the `List`. So you don't have to sort in your `equals` and `compareTo` methods.

To your question regarding the `compareTo` method: 
if the size of `arguments` is the same iterate over both `arguments` lists comparing the same indices of the `Variables` via `compareTo` and return the first result which is `!= 0`. (Or '0' if all elements are equal)

One possible solution:

```
public int compareTo(Operation v) {
  int res = type.compareTo(v.type);
  if (res != 0) return res;

  res = name.compareTo(v.name);
  if (res != 0) return res;

  if (arguments.size() != v.arguments.size()) return arguments.size() - v.arguments.size();

  for (int i = 0; i < arguments.size(); ++i) {
    res = arguments.get(i).compareTo(v.arguments.get(i));
    if (res != 0) return res;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: so just add Collections.sort(arguments); in addArgument function?

Comment: yes - but just to avoid the duplicated sorting in `equals` and `compareTo`